# Hovering cursor over an image?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a cell of an NSImageView subclass. I want a small textbox to popup when the user overs their cursor over the image.

An example of what I am looking for is the "yellow textbox" that pops up when you hover your cursor over an image in a web browser. For example hovering your cursor over the Google logo brings up the text "Google" in a small textbox.

How would I go about doing this? Note I am developing an app for OSX **not** iOS. I am using Xcode 3.2.6.

Comment: If you're referring to tooltips, the easiest way to use them is `setToolTip:` (with an `NSString*` value) in `NSView`.  There are other methods that give you more control over them.

Comment: @KevinGrant Exactly what I was looking for! Could you post your comment as an answer so I can select it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with `setToolTip:` on an `NSView` (for a string) or use other tooltip-related `NSView` methods to have more control over the result.